# <%= hidden_field_tag :site_password,@userprofile.map{|r| [r.site_password]} %>

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i dont want to store hidden value in database. but i want to get"site_password" field value  from @userpforile table and use into @userpublish table where i am only using this "site_password" field value for login. so how can i pass this "site_password" field value through hidden_field_tag.

<%=  f.select :site_email, @userprofile.map {|r| [r.site_email]}  %>
with their site_email?

<%= f.hidden_field_tag :site_password,@userprofile.map{|r| [r.site_password]} %>

when i am using on this way it is give me error bcz of this "f" is a object of @userpublish table. so how can do operation on submit button. plz give me solution as it as possible

Comment: I dont think you need `[r.site_password]`. Just use `r.site_password`. Otherwise it will create a 2 dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use 'f'. Just use like this

```
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'yourFieldName', @userprofile.map{|r| [r.site_password]} %>
```

Now submit will work and you will get the parameter like params[:yourFieldName]